# Using a bind variable in an INSERT statement

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I need to ask the user for a variable, use that variable in a `SELECT` statement, and then use that same variable in an `INSERT` statement. Right now I am just trying to get using the variable for an `INSERT` to work:

```
var num NUMBER(10)
exec num := &ExpNum
INSERT INTO ExpDet 
VALUES(num, &LineNum, &Descrip, &Amt, &HCode, &SubCode)
```

When I run this, I get an error saying

> Bind variable 'num' is not declared.

Do I have the right idea here, or do I need to use some other method entirely?

Answer (score 1):

A working example:

```
SQL> create table expdet
  2    (num number,
  3     linenum number,
  4     descrip varchar2(20),
  5     amt number,
  6     hcode number,
  7     subcode number);

Table created.

SQL> var num number
SQL> exec :num := &expnum
Enter value for expnum: 100

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> insert into expdet values
  2    (:num, &linenum, &descrip, &amt, &hcode, &subcode);
Enter value for linenum: 1
Enter value for descrip: 'a'
Enter value for amt: 1
Enter value for hcode: 1
Enter value for subcode: 1
old   2:   (:num, &linenum, &descrip, &amt, &hcode, &subcode)
new   2:   (:num, 1, 'a', 1, 1, 1)

1 row created.

SQL>
```